# HTML FORM - have form action="" occur before onsubmit=""

Tags: action, forms, onsubmit

I've got a pop-up form, onsubmit it closes itself and also refreshes the parent screen. 
It uses action="x.php" to transfer session data.
My problem is that in the form onsubmit="js()" is occuring before action="x.php", so the data doesn't get sent before the window closes.
How can I switch the order that these are executed?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery AJAX to submit the form and perform your onsubmit code in the success callback.

```
$("#formID").submit(function() {
    /*
    Do client side validation before you submit the form with AJAX
    */
    var formData = $("#formID").serialize();
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "x.php",  
      data: formData,  
      success: function() {  
        /*
        The actions you want to perform
        window.close(); // etc etc
        */
      }  
    });
    return false; // stop default form submit because we're using ajax
});
```